# Why doesn't React.PropsWithRef<P> add 'ref' property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I encountered weird (in my opinion) code while checking [sources](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L64). This line of code uses `React.PropsWithRef<P>` generic type this way

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<
  React.PropsWithRef<React.PropsWithChildren<ErrorBoundaryProps>>,
  ErrorBoundaryState
> {...}
```

which in fact is

```
/** Ensures that the props do not include string ref, which cannot be forwarded */
type PropsWithRef<P> =
// Just "P extends { ref?: infer R }" looks sufficient, but R will infer as {} if P is {}.
'ref' extends keyof P
  ? P extends { ref?: infer R }
    ? string extends R
      ? PropsWithoutRef<P> & { ref?: Exclude<R, string> }
      : P
    : P
  : P;
```

something different. So instead of adding `ref` property to the type (as `React.PropsWithChildren<P>` does with `children`) as we can think from the name it just checks against string refs. It makes me confused why it's named this way and used in the library. If ref forwarding is used then `React.forwardRef` HOC should return a proper type and `ref` is passed as a second argument to the render function se we don't even need `ref` in props.

Could someone clarify it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is for backwards compatibility with the old string refs, where you could do `<div ref="myRef"/>`.  String refs can't be forwarded so they need to be removed.  I agree that the name is confusing.